# Alter CLOB without SOURCE_LOOKUP

Tags: replicate, attunity

I am attempting to alter CLOB data to `STRING(3999)` row by row in a table. I am currently using `SUBSTR([fieldname],1,3999)`, however when checking the result table against the source table it shows a `NULL` result despite data existing within the source.

Using:

```
substr(source_lookup(1,[SCHEMA],[TABLE],[FIELD],[KEYDEFS],[KEYS]),1,3900)
```

works, however it alters the processing time from 5 minutes to just shy of 2 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attunity provided workaround for this issue is as follows:

Create a secondary task, specifically loading just the key fields and the CLOB data. When this is ported into the staging area a view should be created using DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR() to convert it. Compose can then match the ETL set to the view via a lookup matching on the keys.